# Can't connect to secure RPI access point

Tags: wireless, dhcp, wireless-adapter

I can't connect to my RPI access point (using isc-dhcp-server and hostapd with the Edimax EW-7811Un N150 using the drivers suggested and installed following "sk00t3r"'s instructions on the adafruit forums (linked below)) unless I omit certain values in /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf (shown in the screenshots below) to make it "open", passwordless.

https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=47716

Working (so, values omitted in hostapd to make the ap open):
[[image: ]]

You can clearly see my nexus 7 connecting here absolutely fine, it also works with my windows 7 desktop.

Not working (so, values that were omitted in the above screenshot are not):
[[image: ]]

I feel like I've probably made a stupid mistake or something, I'm a bit new to this. Points if you get the Dr.Strangelove reference, anyway.